# I want to make it so javascript only runs after a certain command is verified

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have this code

HTML

```
<p @click="so">Sobre</p>    
<div class="content2" id="myDiv" v-if="i==2">
```

Vue.js

```
    var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        i: 1/*,
        j: 1*/
    },
    methods:{
        so(){
            this.i = 2
        }
    }
})
```

JavaScript

```
            $(".num1").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 500 })
            $(".num2").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 1500 })
            $(".num3").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 2000 })
            $(".num4").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 2500 })
            $(".num5").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 3000 })
```

Basically vue code hides the div by making it into a comment until i click on the p class, and the JavaScript code is a simple counter for numbers(that are inside the div) but the JavaScript code runs right away. How do i make the JavaScript code only run when i==2 or when it removes the div from comment?

Comment: Java != JavaScript.  They are completely different languages.

Comment: Run it in the `so` method?

Comment: what should i toss in there i tried (so(){
            this.i = 2,
            $(".num1").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 500 }),
            $(".num2").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 1500 }),
            $(".num3").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 2000 }),
            $(".num4").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 2500 }),
            $(".num5").counterUp({ delay: 10, time: 3000 })
        }) didnt work

Comment: still didn't fix anyone can help?